# Panel Tabulator passes the values of the selected row to another function

Tags: python, dataframe, panel, tabulator

I am building a panel app and hit a block. What I want to accomplish is to pass certain values of the row selected from the dataframe visualized by Tabulator widget to another function, which is responsible for loading another dataframe and producing predefined plots based on these values. I can manage to get to the point where the selection event gives me the required data, but how can I link the updated values to the input of another function. How can I make the function monitor the selection result and perform its task dynamically?
Part of this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
from panel.widgets import Tabulator
pn.extension('tabulator')

def click(event):
    print(df_parameters_short.iloc[event.row]['TIC_ID'])
    print(df_parameters_short.iloc[event.row]['modes'])
    selected_tic_id = df_parameters_short.iloc[event.row]['TIC_ID']
    selected_mode = df_parameters_short.iloc[event.row]['modes']
    

def show_dataframe(base_dataframe):
    
    selectable_table = pn.widgets.Tabulator(base_dataframe,
                                            disabled=True,
                                            selection=[0],
                                            selectable=1,
                                            pagination='remote',
                                            page_size=20,
                                            show_index=False)
    
    row_selection = selectable_table.on_click(click)
    

    return selectable_table


tabulator_data = show_dataframe(df_parameters_short)
tabulator_data.servable()
```

So the TIC_ID and the mode string must be updated on the input of another function. For example:

```
def plotter(path, TIC_ID, mode):
    df = pd.read_csv(path + TIC_ID + '/' + mode + '/results.csv')
    fig = df.hvplot.scatter(x='phase', y='flux')
    return fig
```

I tried to set up a watcher but I couldn't get it to work, nor the depends module.
I'm quite new to panels and dashboards, but I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, I just haven't found it yet.